# "Make a renovation" and "have a vacation"

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure "had a vacation" and "made a renovation" are correct. I am looking for the verb to use before "land" to say that it was also "renovated". The rest of the text is provided for context.

"Last summer we had a vacation in an old village. The house we were staying at was made of chestnut wood. The owner of the house made a renovation of the house and it's land."
I changed it into:

"Last summer we went on vacation to an old village. The house we were staying at was made of chestnut wood. The owner of the house renovated it and (verb) the land."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your changes. As to "land", on could say "landscaped", but the repetition makes "landscaped the land" ungraceful. Maybe, "landscaped the yard".
You're right to separate "land" from "house", because it's not natural to say "renovated the land".